# Battery Power when running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in dual boot

Tags: power-management, battery

This is only a general question in order for me to get a better idea of my dual boot (windows 8 & Ubuntu) systems.

I noticed that every time I run Ubuntu (which is becoming more often) the battery power gets consumed really fast. I am not performing any special tasks at the moment, just getting to know the system, for example, sound settings, watching videos, surfing the net and so on. When I do the same thing in Windows 8 the battery lives a considerable amount of time longer.

Is this something to do with Ubuntu or is it because of the dual boot that I have going on? In other words, if I start running Ubuntu all by itself on my laptop, will it be more power consuming than Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

No it has nothing to do with dual boot. 
Most probably there are drivers that's work is not fully optimized like in windows 8 which make it consume power, I had this problem with my AMD driver, on windows battery keep working for 4H but in Ubuntu 12.10 it was like 1H.

Problem with me was fixed when i used Ubuntu 14.04LTS , and also a power management that can extend the battery life

You can install TLP power manager

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

and start using it by :

```
sudo tlp start
```

It should write in the terminal

```
TLP started in ac/battery mode.
```

Wish it help you

Comment: I think it started to help because my laptop was heating up and it started to cool down as soon as I started. Did it heat up with you too? Or is the heating up problem a completely different issue?

Comment: Yes it was heating up with me too, Specially that my laptop is HP.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Moustafa3390's answer I'll to like to add that you might be having a Nvidia Optimus enabled laptop. In Ubuntu by default the Nvidia Graphics card is generally always onand hence the battery gets used up rapidly. I suggest you either install 'nvidia-prime' from the official repo or install 'bumblebee' to enhance battery life.

You can refer here for instructions
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: Would it make a difference if it was an AMD Radeon Graphics Card?

Comment: Actually I am not much familiar with AMD Radeon Graphics card, but a friend of mine had similar problem and he was able to completely disable his Radeon card in Ubuntu which solved the problem. I think the official `flgrx` package does support hybrid setup to some extent.